# object instantiation in c++

Tags: c++, object, instantiation

In C++ is it true that if you instantiate an object of a class, that for every
object all of methods of the class are copied for the new object?

I tried to point to a method of a class with two different objects, but I'd problems
with pointer to member.

Any idea?

Comment: You cannot instantiate objects, you can only instantiate types and templates...

Comment: @Griwes An object is an instance of a class - creating an instance is often referred to as instantiation.

Comment: @Casey, sure, but you are instantiating the *class*, not the object (IOW: you are making an instance of a class, not an instance of an object).

Answer (score 7):

> In C++ is it true that if you instantiate an object of a class, that for every object all of methods of the class are copied for the new object?

No, *member functions* are not usually copied anywhere. A different implicit parameter `this` is instead passed to any non-static member function, for each object of that class-type.

Answer (score 6):

**No, that is absolutely *not* true.**

Class instances (objects) contain *data members*. Function members look like they're "in" the class, but that's only for scoping and such: your function code doesn't "exist" inside the type, and it certainly doesn't exist inside the object<sup>†</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> [I *think* it could, theoretically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21316610/560648), in that the standard doesn't outright forbid it. But honestly, no. Just no.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The code for a class exists only once.

For getting a pointer to a member function (probably what you meant by method), take a look at [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and for attaching the function call to different objects, take a look at [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: That is completely not what that Standard functionality does.

Comment: @DeadMG: What do you mean?

Comment: The term 'method' is not well-defined in C++. Did you mean to imply a function that is a member? Or one that is non-static? Or one that is virtual? Or one that is pure? To avoid misunderstandings, prefer standardized terminology: instead of 'method' say 'function' prefixed with those specifiers that are relevant.

Comment: I was trying to use the same terminology as the original poster, but have modified it to be more difficult to read.

Comment: @woolstar: Sometimes precision comes at a cost. In this instance, the cost is truly negligible...