# Does C++ as a standard prohibit the storage of member functions inside individual class instances?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In C++ implementations, typically code is not stored (in any form) inside class instances. The code segment is not in the same memory space as objects and the like. This means that member functions are not "stored" inside class instances.

But when [a question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21316374/560648) about this, I got to wondering: to what extent, if at all, does the standard *prohibit* member functions being stored inside their encapsulating class, to the extent that instantiating the class makes a copy of those functions? Theoretically, could I make an implementation that worked this way? And could it even remotely abide by the common ABIs?

Comment: It will not conform to the ABIs, but that does not mean that you cannot build it. Whether the standard allows for that or not I will not attempt to guess (or check) but none of the existing ABIs would allow for this.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Sorry for being unclear: the question about ABIs is more of a tangential addendum than a supposed condition for implementation feasibility.

Comment: That is why the previous is a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: And a mighty fine one it is, too!

Comment: It would be awkward to meet the standard layout requirements, if you had functions in a base class and data in a derived class.

Comment: What to you mean by *prohibit to not storing*? As far as I know if a member function is not virtual then is handled by compiles simple as function with implicit argument for passing *this* pointer. And when function is virtual pointer to it is stored inside vtable in an instance of a class. So can also have a pointer to a member function and initiate it with whatever member function you want as long as its normally available in scope you are using it. So, what exactly you meant?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Post that as an answer, you are right. Standard layout cannot be guaranteed for types with different member functions

Comment: Do you mean within, as in the `sizeof`, or within, as in a copy can throw exceptions from allocation of the space for member functions, or within, as in the runtime does something completely non-observable that behaves exactly as-if the runtime did not do it?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Good point. Also, aliasing is allowed via a union if two standard-layout structs share a common initial sequence (and that, AFAIK, only takes data members into account).

Comment: @Yakk: The latter, I think. But any of them really.

Comment: The runtime can do *anything* as-if it never happened.  So are you looking for a proof that you cannot do it as-if it never happened?  The issue is that all 3 of them are very different questions.

Comment: Once the class has a virtual function, though, you can probably do what you like. And given that it's absurd to put the code in the objects at all, it's *marginally* more absurd to do so for non-virtual functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If, in C++, code were a first-class value, then the code for a member function would be simply a `const static` class member, and you would no more expect to find that in an instance than you would any other static data member. (§ 9.4.2: "A static data member is not part of the subobjects of a class.")

However, code is not considered a value, and furthermore you cannot even construct a pointer to a member function (although you can construct a "pointer to member", that is not really a pointer since it is not usable without a reference to an instance). That makes member function code different both from static data members and non-member functions, both of which allow the creation of free-standing pointers, which furthermore have equality guarantees which (more or less) preclude copying.

Class instances do contain a reference to *virtual* member functions (indirectly, in most implementations; the pointer is actually to a static vtable) which must be copied when a new instance is created. No requirement is made on the size of the reference, so in theory (as far as I know) there is nothing to stop an implementation from avoiding the indirections and storing the entire code anew for each instance of the class.

But there is an exception for standard-layout types, which is a subset of classes with no virtual member functions, expressed in § 9.12/18, which requires that two standard-layout types with identical initial members have identical layout for the initial members. Recalling that standard-layout objects must be simply copyable with memcpy (§3.9/3), must be contiguous in memory (§1.8/5), and must include their members in order (§9.12/13), this requirement makes it effectively impossible to include class-specific static data in any standard-layout object, which would include the code for member functions.

So I conclude that at least for standard-layout objects, the C++ standard does prohibit the storage of static data, including code for member functions, within the object representation.

Comment: I don't think it is right to include *static* into the discussion, the question is a bit more whether the function code could be managed as a non-static data member (i.e. copied in each object). There are different reasons why `static` data cannot be stored per-object the most obvious of which is that it must be *shared* by all objects. But does that apply to functions? For standard layout the requirements would force the functions not to be managed inside the object, that is correct but the whole discussion on `static` is misleading

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: A static const member must be shared by all objects, but the only thing which prevents copying is that it might have its address taken; otherwise, it could be treated as a non-static const member (leaving aside the standard layout requirements). For me, that is precisely the same as the code for a member function. You are, of course, free to disagree :)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to include trivially copyable types? How would sizeof work? And what someone who just fills the object using memset()? I can't see how it could be done, even if you wanted to.

Comment: @david.pfx: All trivially copyable classes have standard layout. A standard layout class may have a non-trivial destructor making it non-trivially copyable. Scalar objects are irrelevant because they have no member functions. So, yes, I meant standard layout. memset() has undefined behaviour on non standard layout objects (and on some standard layout objects). sizeof provides the size of an object. I don't see how that is relevant; even if an object included redundant static data, it would still have a known size.

Comment: @rici: By my reading, trivially copyable includes struct/class with access control, where the members might be out of order and therefore not SL. Your other arguments would apply to TC as well as SL. [There are also SL that are not TC; the intersection is POD]

Comment: @david.pfx: ah, yes, you are right that TC is not a subset of SL. However, the union layout provision I was relying upon only applies to SL objects. I should make the argument more explicit in the answer. Thinking more about sizeof, I think it is possible to argue that sizeof must be computable at compile time without knowing the code size of member functions, which would preclude the object size being influenced by the code size of functions. I'm not yet prepared to make that argument, though; I'll edit the answer if/when I am.

Comment: Fair enough. I can't help thinking it's an argument about how many angels can dance on the head of a pin. The only merit is that it gets us thinking about the unthinkable.

Comment: @david.pfx: `dancing-angels` is a synonym for the `language-lawyer` tag. Or it ought to be.

Comment: So, here is a game.  We stick 1 k of padding between each standard layout member.  In that padding, we encode functions (if large, they invoke exterior "helpers" say).  Now, our objects are copyable with memcopy, are contiguous in memory (padding not ruled out), and their members are included in order.  Two standard layout types with the same prefix have the "same layout" for their member variables -- only the part *between* is different, and a memcopy from one to another breaks things (!).  In short, is there anything preventing the **space between** member variables from being significant?

Comment: @Yakk: Good question. I'd say the object initialization rules prevent that (any object must be either zero initialized or default initialized; in the former case, the padding bits are set to 0), but you might think that's a technicality. (Which it is, but this is a language-lawyer question, no?). In any event, there is no guarantee that 1k is enough even for all the stubs, since there might be only one possible gap and more than 1024 member functions, so I don't think that it affects my original answer, but I'm still open to being convinced otherwise.